# Regex check if two strings have one word in common

Tags: regex

What would be the most generic way of comparing two sentences and find if they have a word in common.

For ex

sentence A: My cat is black.

sentence B: The white cat climbs a tree.

Match should be cat.

Comment: What effort have you've put into this to try and find a solution yourself? This isn't the regex drive-thru. We're not a code or regex writing service, where you post a vague description of your requirements and we crank out an expression for you. Have you made any attempt at all to figure this out on your own?

Comment: Actually, what @Ghost probably meant was "A regex is a terrible tool for this problem. Why are you insisting on a regex?"

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to split sentences into words and then check if any work from sentence one is in sentence two (turn them into lowercase).

One probably crazy idea to do this with one regex operation would be to concatenate the strings with some clear separator (like `__SEP__`) and then try to match

```
/\b(\w+)\b.*?__SEP__.*?\b\1\b/
```

It checks if there are twice the same sequences of letters separated by word boundaries around a string that contains `__SEP__`.